# Session [(null externalkey)] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions. Active sessions are[ext. key 2a7...]

Tags: php, selenium, webdriver

When attempting to create a new RemoteWebDriver, everything goes well. When I attempt to get a URL on the newly created webdriver, I get the error:

`Session [(null externalkey)] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions.
Active sessions are[ext. key 2a7...]`

I'm redacting the guid as it's irrelevant and takes up too much space.

Here is my docker-compose file

```
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.141.59-20200409
    container_name: selenium-hub
    environment:
      - GRID_MAX_SESSION=20
      - GRID_TIMEOUT=12000
      - GRID_NEW_SESSION_WAIT_TIMEOUT=30000
      - GRID_DEBUG=true
      - GRID_CLEAN_UP_CYCLE=20000
      - START_XVFB=false
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"

  selenium-chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug:3.141.59-20200409
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
```

Any help is appreciated